# PayPal lightbox won't open in iPhone safari/web app; 'win.location' undefined

Tags: javascript, paypal, lightbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

(works fine in `Chrome` on the `iPhone`)

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'win.location') in dg.js line 3
```

And the lightbox does not open.

The code in question inside PayPal's [dg.js](https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js) is:

```
startFlow: function (url) {
    var win = that._render();
    if (win.location) {
        win.location = url;
    } else {
        win.src = url;
    }
}
```

So does mobile `Safari` not understand `that._render()`?  How do I get around this?

If it matters, I'm using `Adaptive Payments`, calling it like so:

```
var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({
    trigger: null, 
    expType: 'light'
});
dg.startFlow('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=' +data.paykey);
```

I don't have any problems getting the `payKey` & the entire `payflow` works on desktops and in mobile browsers other than `Safari` (it works on desktop `Safari`).  It also does not work when our site is run as an `iOS` web app, which I assume is just a shell for `Safari` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a couple of ways to get around this...`location.replace` with the PayPal URL or using your own lightbox.  I used [easybox](https://code.google.com/p/easybox/).

```
// Replace
dg.startFlow('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=' +data.paykey);

// with
var RUNNING_AS_WEB_APP = (window.navigator.standalone == true ? true : false);
if (RUNNING_AS_WEB_APP === false) {
    dg.startFlow('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=' +data.paykey);
} else {
    location.replace('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=' +data.paykey);
    // Or, lightbox option: 
    // $.easybox([{url: 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=' +data.paykey, width: 320, height: 480}]);
}
```

Comment: I did not have any luck with a lightbox (I tried magnific). I ended up having to integrate the mini flow for iOS, which does work albeit with a new browser window.

Comment: @Alex I am also facing a similar issue. My app is an IOS app. What I do is create paykey and load UIWebView using mini browser URL. But I cannot detect when user completes a payment or cancels . Return and cancel urls are not called? How did you implement mini flow in IOS. Please help me.

Comment: I am actually in the process of tearing this integration out of my system. From what I've gotten from PayPal support, this flow is unsupported inside a WebView and PayPal is not going to fix it because they've effectively stopped development on the Classic APIs. There is a workaround to remove the JavaScript and just do a straight redirect to PayPal, passing the payKey as a query parameter, but the user experience is awful (not mobile optimized in the least).

Answer (score 2):

I can explain why you are seeing this error.
Safari on iOS only allows a window to be opened as a result of a user click/touch event.

The DGFlow._render() function executes:

```
window.open('', "PPDG");
```

which returns null if triggered by anything other than a user click/touch event.

I am guessing you are issuing an XMLHttpRequest to generate a PayRequest/PayKey on the server and then in the onsuccess callback you are calling DGFlow.startFlow().

The solution is two split the process into two steps:

1. When the user is ready to checkout, issue the call to the server to
   generate the pay key.
2. Then, present the user with a button to Checkout with PayPal and when that is clicked, call DGFlow.startFlow()

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mini browser experience where expType=mini.  Seems to work better than the lightbox on mobile devices.

[Adaptive Payments without modal box or popups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283272/adaptive-payments-without-modal-box-or-popups/17729106)

Comment: We tried mini too, it was still throwing the same error in Safari on iOS/iOS web app though =/